# Mysql count, return all fields, if nothing counted return 0

Tags: mysql, count, null, return, zero

I've been looking around for alot of people having the same problem, but the solution seems te be much more different?!

I have a 3 tables:

```
+-------------------------------------------+
| ITEM: itemid(pk), status(fk), owner(fk)   |
|                                           |
| STATUS: statusid(pk), statusname          |
|                                           |
| OWNER: ownerid(pk), ownername             |
+-------------------------------------------+
```

I have 2 status: *1: Available*, *2: Broken*.

In this case there is only ONE owner with ONE broken item.
I am using this code. First it was different, but it seems LEFT JOIN and GROUP/ORDER BY should do the trick. Unfortunately for me.

```
SELECT ownername, SUM(price) AS  'totalbrokenpriceeach', COUNT( itemid ) AS  'totalbrokenitemseach'
                                FROM item
                                LEFT JOIN owner ON item.owner = owner.ownerid
                                LEFT JOIN status on item.status = status.statusid
                                WHERE statusid='2'
                                GROUP BY ownerid
```

This returns:

```
ownername   totalbrokenpriceeach    totalbrokenitemseach
Owner #1            60                          1
Owner #5            180                         4
```

I'd like to have returned:

```
ownername   totalbrokenpriceeach    totalbrokenitemseach
Owner #1            60                          1
Owner #2            0                           0
Owner #3            0                           0
Owner #4            0                           0
Owner #5            180                         4
```

What to do? Anyone any solutions?

EDIT:

```
         OWNER                          
+-----------------------+
| ownerid ownername     |
|     1:    Henk        |
|     2:    Jan         |
|     3:    Piet        |
|     4:    Klaas       |
+-----------------------+

         STATUS
+-----------------------+
| statusid statusbeschr |
|     1:    Available   |
|     2:    Broken      |
+-----------------------+

         ITEM
+--------------------------------------+
| itemid    price     owner     status |
|     1:    90          1          1   |
|     2:    40          2          1   |
|     3:    20          2          1   |
|     4:    120         3          2   |
+--------------------------------------+

I need returned:

+-------------------------------------------------------+
| ownername    SumOfBrokenItems   AmountOfBrokenItems   |
|     Henk:       0                       0             |
|     Jan:        0                       0             |
|     Piet:       120                     1             |
|     Klaas:      0                       0             |
+-------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Try changing the first LEFT JOIN to a RIGHT JOIN.

Comment: I tried, right, right outer, left, left outer, left inner, even combinating the two untill sql started to whine :P

Comment: My bad, I thought the status was a column from owner, not item.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT  a.ownername, 
        SUM(price) AS  totalbrokenpriceeach, 
        COUNT(b.itemid) AS  totalbrokenitemseach
FROM    owner a
        LEFT JOIN   item b
            ON a.ownerID = b.owner
        LEFT JOIN   status c
            ON b.status = c.statusID AND 
               c.StatusID = 2
GROUP BY    ownername
```

**UPDATE 1**

```
SELECT  a.ownername, 
        SUM(CASE WHEN c.statusbeschr = 'Broken' THEN b.price ELSE 0 END) AS  totalbrokenpriceeach, 
        SUM(CASE WHEN c.statusbeschr = 'Broken' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS  totalbrokenitemseach
FROM    owner a
        LEFT JOIN   item b
            ON a.ownerID = b.owner
        LEFT JOIN   status c
            ON b.status = c.statusID        
GROUP BY a.ownerid
ORDER BY a.ownerid
```

- [**SQLFiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/77a59/4)

Comment: This counts all fields together with the value. Only need that for status 2, and return 0 with the owner if status = 2 is not found.

Comment: Same result. Counts all. I get Owner #1: 36791, 246 - Owner #2: 1227, 14 - etc.

Comment: @IvanM can you add sample records on your question?

Comment: edited my question. Not sure if that is what you are asking for.

Comment: In advance I'm thanking you for really getting into it. Appreciate it. Though it returns everything zero now.

Comment: did you see the fiddle right? it's the same as what you wanted.

Comment: Oh wow... yes. It is what I want! But my phpadmin didn't give that in return :/ weird...

Comment: Perhaps because of the (fk) constraints? Can't think of more, the fields are all the same.

Comment: OHH MY bad! I see. I wrote BROKEN, it supposed to be in another language! Thanks aloT =D=D+D+D

Comment: maybe it has to do with the records on your table. hehe weird.